# How do I add pagination or a pagination limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pagination, implode

I want to know how to add a pagination limit to my query.

The query without the limit.

```
if(!empty($sqlParts))
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE " .implode( " AND " , $sqlParts);                        
}
```

The query with the limit.

```
if(!empty($sqlParts)) 
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE " .implode( " AND " , $sqlParts) ' LIMIT ' $offset ',' $no_of_records_per_page;                        
}
```

The idea is to display a certain amount of data from my database before you can go to the next page to display the rest.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' LIMIT '' - this is my error with the code above.

Comment: Pagination without ordering doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The syntax is wrong. You have to concatenate the string with ".".

Comment: ```$sql = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $sqlParts)." LIMIT $offset,$no_of_records_per_page";``` - Thank you my syntax was completely wrong. I just missed that part. Although I have to work pagination into the code.

Answer (score -1):

Please print the SQL before the execution
I think you are missing $offset or $no_of_records_per_page value

Comment: This is the code before building the query array

```
if (isset($_GET['pageno']))
 {
     $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
 }
 else 
{
     $pageno = 1;
 }
 $no_of_records_per_page = 3;
 $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;
```
This is the code to count and get the amount of data it should display
```
$total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
$total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
``

Answer (score -1):

Try this, It would be easier to fix if you print and send the query

```
if (isset($_GET['pageno']) && $_GET['pageno'] > 0) {
    $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
} else {
    $pageno = 1;
}
$no_of_records_per_page = 3;
$offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

if(!empty($sqlParts) && is_array($sqlParts))
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE " .implode( " AND " , $sqlParts) ' LIMIT ' $offset ',' $no_of_records_per_page; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @GajananTagadpalle . Worked like a charm. Although How do I implement Pagination? So that it displays the **$no_of_records_per_page** and if I go to the next page it goes on from the last record?